# Incorrect Syntax near "=" in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is the query causing error:

```
EXECUTE (' UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT ' + ' SET ' + @lcrcolumn_name + ' = ' + @lcrcolumn_total)
```

Comment: what are the values for `@lcrcolumn_name` and `@lcrcolumn_total` ?

Comment: if you are updating varchar column then syntex : EXECUTE (' UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT ' + ' SET ' + @lcrcolumn_name + ' = ' ' + @lcrcolumn_total+''')

Comment: Side note : use sp_executesql to reduce sql injection chance

Comment: sp_executesql by itself won't protect from SQL Injection if the statement is generated by string concatenation. Using parameterized queries will

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is ok, probably you have wrong valye for column name, or you need to cast @lcrcolumn_tot as nvarchar.

Give us the value for the variable, pr check by yourself with the flowing statement:

```
declare @lcrcolumn_name nvarchar(50) = 'blabla',
        @lcrcolumn_tot nvarchar(50) = 10
declare @sql nvarchar(4000);

set @sql = ' UPDATE facetswrk.dbo.ODS_SUBSC_PREM_REPORT SET ' + @lcrcolumn_name + ' = ' + @lcrcolumn_tot

print @sql
execute(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to print the dynamic sql before you execute it to understand what is causing the error, you may have some data value in @lcrcolumn_name and @lcrcolumn_total which may be creating the problem.